# How do I create objects from json data on a webpage?

Tags: java, json, gson

So I am trying to create a list of objects based upon some json data on a webpage.

My thought process goes a little bit like this.
Download the source of the website as a string.
Pass that string into Gson that then creates objects from the json string.
Given that I have a object that has the correct fields.

So something like this

```
String data = getURLSource(link);
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
Gson g = new Gson();
Item p = g.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), Item.class);


public static String getURLSource(String url) throws IOException
    {
        URL urlObject = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = urlObject.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

        return toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    }

    private static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")))
        {
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
```

That's going to throw errors so my question is.
What's the proper way of getting json data from a websource and then creating a list of objects based upon that data.

This is the source of the data
https://osrsitemapi.azurewebsites.net/api/items

Comment: "That's going to throw errors" <-- Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest to use `Jackson` library which has a great `API` to work with `JSON` payloads.

Assume you have class like below:

```
class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean members;
    private int sp;
    private int buy_average;
    private int buy_quantity;
    private int sell_average;
    private int sell_quantity;
    private int overall_average;
    private int overall_quantity;
    private String image;

    // getters, setters, toString

}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL urlObject = new URL("https://osrsitemapi.azurewebsites.net/api/items");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Item[] items = mapper.readValue(urlObject, Item[].class);

        System.out.println("Number of items: " + items.length);
        System.out.println("Show 10 items:");
        Stream.of(items).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Number of items: 3344
Show 10 items:
Item{id=2, name='Cannonball', members=true, sp=5, buy_average=202, buy_quantity=641812, sell_average=202, sell_quantity=1075463, overall_average=202, overall_quantity=1717275, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/7/73/Cannonball_detail.png/150px-Cannonball_detail.png?8724b'}
Item{id=36, name='Candle', members=true, sp=3, buy_average=182, buy_quantity=39, sell_average=136, sell_quantity=5, overall_average=177, overall_quantity=44, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/8/83/Candle_detail.png/50px-Candle_detail.png?9db36'}
Item{id=30, name='Bucket of wax', members=true, sp=6, buy_average=820, buy_quantity=10, sell_average=0, sell_quantity=0, overall_average=820, overall_quantity=10, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/0/0a/Bucket_of_wax_detail.png/130px-Bucket_of_wax_detail.png?838bd'}
Item{id=8, name='Cannon stand', members=true, sp=187500, buy_average=191566, buy_quantity=10, sell_average=187186, sell_quantity=22, overall_average=188555, overall_quantity=32, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/7/76/Cannon_stand_detail.png/150px-Cannon_stand_detail.png?c4958'}
Item{id=43, name='Adamant arrowtips', members=true, sp=40, buy_average=94, buy_quantity=2321, sell_average=99, sell_quantity=19945, overall_average=99, overall_quantity=22266, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/7/7e/Adamant_arrowtips_detail.png/120px-Adamant_arrowtips_detail.png?bdf02'}
Item{id=12, name='Cannon furnace', members=true, sp=187500, buy_average=192005, buy_quantity=11, sell_average=188086, sell_quantity=19, overall_average=189523, overall_quantity=30, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/d/d0/Cannon_furnace_detail.png/130px-Cannon_furnace_detail.png?c4958'}
Item{id=40, name='Iron arrowtips', members=true, sp=2, buy_average=5, buy_quantity=6260, sell_average=4, sell_quantity=5817, overall_average=5, overall_quantity=12077, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/5/5d/Iron_arrowtips_detail.png/120px-Iron_arrowtips_detail.png?7d8a1'}
Item{id=42, name='Mithril arrowtips', members=true, sp=16, buy_average=49, buy_quantity=16934, sell_average=0, sell_quantity=0, overall_average=49, overall_quantity=16934, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/2/21/Mithril_arrowtips_detail.png/120px-Mithril_arrowtips_detail.png?3b5f0'}
Item{id=39, name='Bronze arrowtips', members=true, sp=1, buy_average=8, buy_quantity=100, sell_average=4, sell_quantity=8065, overall_average=4, overall_quantity=8165, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/8/84/Bronze_arrowtips_detail.png/120px-Bronze_arrowtips_detail.png?0c3c4'}
Item{id=10, name='Cannon barrels', members=true, sp=187500, buy_average=188888, buy_quantity=9, sell_average=187594, sell_quantity=19, overall_average=188010, overall_quantity=28, image='https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/5/54/Cannon_barrels_detail.png/125px-Cannon_barrels_detail.png?7aa5b'}
```

1. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
2. [Jackson JSON Tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson)

Comment: That looks really nice! Can't seem to find the Gradle implementation though

Comment: Do you mean `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.8'`? See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8

Comment: I had to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8`

Comment: Yes, the newest version is always the best choice!

Comment: Is there a way to populate that array of `Item` at the start? Because I am using a AsyncTask method and I am currently running that code every time I click a button.

Comment: @MarkDenom, it is but you need to create new question because it sounds like a totally different problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to get rid of the XML wrapper around the JSON data from the source, if you look at the source you will find it does not start with valid JSON but this:

`<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">`

Also the data contains more than one item, so you should ask Gson to deliver a `List<Item>` rather than just `Item`.

If your Item-class provides the correct fields, this should then work.

Comment: API updated, and for the fields, do I need to have all of them? Even if I only want lets say the name?

Comment: I would suggest to have all of them. If you really just want the name you can use GsonBuilder to get the Gson-Instance and use 'addDeserializationExclusionStrategy' to exclude all fields except for name.